# Creating IIS Site, with specific attributes, using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I have to repeatedly create sites for work with the same configuration.  Currently, this is a manual process and is time intensive.  I'm trying to simplify using Powershell, but I have almost no experience with the language.  I've cobbled together a script which is composed from snippets I've found all over the web but I can't seem to get the install to work correctly.

I'm way over my head and appreciate any help which can be provided.

There is 1 error with "Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value True -PSPath IIS:\"Default Web Site\$iisAppName" Write-Host "Windows Authentication Enabled for $iisAppName"" it is trying to write to a very strange path.

Aside from that, the site doesn't function correctly. There are some options from the directions which I couldn't figure out how to accomplish. The site seems to only be partly deployed.

Here are the Install Steps:

```
1   Extract the contents of TestSite.zip from the folder of the Install CD to the File Location recorded in Appendix I.
2   Launch IIS Manager.
3   Select Application Pools from the Connections section of the IIS Manager.
4   Double Click ASP.NET v4.5 application pool.
5   Select .NET Framework v4.0.30319 from the .NET Framework version: dropdown.
6   Click OK.
7   Right-click the ASP.NET v4.5 application pool and select Set Advanced Settings… from the context menu.
8   Select True from the Enable 32-Bit Applications dropdown.
9   Click OK.
10  Expand the Default Web Site. 
11  Right-click TestSite and select Convert to Application from the context menu.
12  Click Connect as...
13  Select the Specific user radial button and click Set…
14  Enter the Domain User Account as recorded in Appendix I into the User Name: textbox.
15  Enter the Domain User Password as recorded in Appendix I into the Password: textbox.
16  Enter the Domain User Password as recorded in Appendix I into the Confirm Password: textbox.
17  Click OK.
18  Click OK.
19  Click Select...
20  Select ASP.NET v4.5 from the Application Pool dropdown.
21  Click OK.
22  Click OK.
23  Double Click Default Document.
24  Move default.aspx to the top of the priority list.
25  Click the Back button.
26  Double Click Authentication.
27  Enable Windows Authentication.
```

Here's the Powershell I have so far:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$iisAppPoolName = ".NET v4.5"
$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion = "v4.0"
$iisAppName = "TestSite"
$zipPath = "C:\Temp\Filename.Version_General.zip"
$directoryPath = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestSite"
$appPath = "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\"
$ADDomain = "Domain"
$CmsUser = "Username"
$ADPassword = "Password"

#Unzip application to wwwroot folder
Write-Host "Unzipping $iisAppName Application to $directoryPath"
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$outpath)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $outpath)
}

Unzip "$zipPath" "$directoryPath"
Write-Host "Zip file ($ZipPath) extracted to ($directoryPath)"

#Create Virtual Directory and then Convert to Application
Write-Host "Creating Virtual Directory and Converting to IIS Application"
New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "Default Web Site" -Name "$iisAppName" -physicalPath "$directoryPath" 
ConvertTo-WebApplication "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\$iisAppName" -ApplicationPool "$iisAppPoolName"
Write-Host "$iisAppName has been Converted to an Application"


#navigate to the app pools root
cd IIS:\AppPools\

#check if the app pool exists
Write-Host "Verify if $iisAppPoolName already exists"
if (!(Test-Path $iisAppPoolName -pathType container))
{
    #create the app pool
    $appPool = New-Item $iisAppPoolName
    $appPool | Set-ItemProperty -Name "managedRuntimeVersion" -Value "$iisAppPoolDotNetVersion"
}
Write-Host "$iisAppPoolName Verified"

#check if the site exists
Write-Host "Checking if $iisAppName already exists, if Not creating Site"
if (Test-Path $iisAppName -pathType container)
{
    return
}

#create the site
$iisApp = New-Item $iisAppName -bindings @{protocol="http";bindingInformation=":80:" + $iisAppName} -physicalPath "$directoryPath"
$iisApp | Set-ItemProperty -Name "applicationPool" -Value "$iisAppPoolName"
Write-Host "$iisAppName Successfully Created"

#set Windows Authentication for the site
Write-Host "Enable windows authentication"
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value True -PSPath IIS:\"Default Web Site\$iisAppName"
Write-Host "Windows Authentication Enabled for $iisAppName"

#test for adding Username and Password to the Site
set-itemproperty "$AppPath$iisAppName" -name userName -value "$ADDomain/$CmsUser"
set-itemproperty "$AppPath$iisAppName" -name password -value "$ADPassword"
```

Comment: What is the specific problem that you are having with this script? Are there errors? Is the site configured incorrectly? Is a specific configuration error? Does the script cause the site to ressurect the <flash> tag and annoy all the visiters?

Comment: There is 1 error with "Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter "/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication" -Name Enabled -Value True -PSPath IIS:\"Default Web Site\$iisAppName"
Write-Host "Windows Authentication Enabled for $iisAppName"" it is trying to write to a very strange path.  Aside from that, the site doesn't function correctly.  There are some options from the directions which I couldn't figure out how to accomplish.  The site seems to only be partly deployed.

Comment: Please update your question with this information.